# Converting a list to a type-safe vector

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to write the function

```
fromList :: [e] -> Vector n e
fromList [] = Nil
fromList (x:xs) = x :| fromList xs
```

using this definition of a vector

```
data Natural where
    Zero :: Natural
    Succ :: Natural -> Natural

data Vector n e where
  Nil  :: Vector Zero e
  (:|) :: e -> Vector n e -> Vector (Succ n) e

infixr :|
```

However, Haskell is giving the error

```
    Couldn't match type 'Zero with 'Succ n0
    Expected type: Vector n e
      Actual type: Vector ('Succ n0) e
    In the expression: x :| fromList xs
    In an equation for `fromList': fromList (x : xs) = x :| fromList xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I believe the error is being thrown because of the type signature of `(:|)`.

Is there a way to get around this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is that your type signature is *universally quantified* in `n`, i.e. it says "for any `n`, we can build a vector of length `n` from the list". Incompatibly, the function definition states that the vector has always the length of the given list.

Basically, you need *existential quantification* to define this function ("depending on the list length, there will be an `n` such that `n` is the length of the result vector"). Discussed only just yesterday, [you can't have existentially-quantified type variables in a signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940487/why-arent-there-existentially-quantified-type-variables-in-ghc-haskell). What you can have though are existential types – preferrably again written as a GADT,

```
data DynVector e where
  DynVector :: Vector n e -> DynVector e
```

Then you can define

```
fromList' :: [e] -> DynVector e
fromList' [] = DynVector Nil
fromList' (x:xs) = case fromList xs of
   DynVector vs -> DynVector $ x :| vs
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - unfortunately, I believe I lose all notion of the size of the vector this way, so it's not really much better than not having `fromList` implemented...

Comment: Well, yeah, kind-of. But that's inevitable, after you _start_ from a type without any type-ensured length guarantees.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way to pass another argument as the length of the list?

Comment: You already do that with your original signature: the `n` is essentially a compile-time argument passed _into_ the function. Indeed you could implement the function this way (you'd need a type class to ensure only natural numbers are passed in, not some other junk), but this wouldn't be safe then either: there's no way to ensure the given list actually has the right length. (What you could do is, cycle and cutoff – would actually be safe with a [non-empty list](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmpty-0.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html).)